# A weird encode character returned from Page.ClientQueryString()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web

Here is the input query string that I enter on the Address Bar:

```
https://myapp.com/myproject/exagoviewer.aspx?act_code=R&rep_own=AAAAAAAAA&report_name=3.52%20SR%20-%20Request%20Time%20Analysis&report_code=3.52%20SR
```

Then, in my code, when I get its query string by calling `Page.ClientQueryString()`, it returns this string

```
act_code=R&rep_own=AAAAAAAAA&report_name=3.52+SR+-+Request+Time+Analysis&report_code=3.52%2520SR
```

You can see there is a weir encode string in the parameter `report_code=3.52%2520SR`, it should be `report_code=3.52%20SR`

Then I tried calling another method `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query` to get the query string, but I got the same issue:

```
?act_code=R&rep_own=AAAAAAAAA&report_name=3.52+SR+-+Request+Time+Analysis&report_code=3.52%2520SR
```

I have no idea what the problem I am facing now. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the root cause. It is caused by the client had called `encodeURIComponent()` one more time before that request came to the server. It means the report_code's value was encoded twice and it converted `%` to `%25`